Angular compilation issue when using xlsx library
An existing Angular project uses 4.2.4 version. We had to add an Excel download feature to the code, hence used the xlsx library. The code worked fine in development when using npm start, however when we're trying to deploy using npm run build and we're getting the error below:

ERROR in vendor.xxx.bundle.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token: name
(_fs)

The above error is shown twice.
In package.json the following are the values:
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4201 --config webpack.dev.config.js",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.prod.config.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "webpack": "~3.5.5",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "1.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.7.1"
}

The following were some of the troubleshooting done:

If we try to remove the node modules and do a npm install, then the project is not working building anymore.
Installed Babel, created babel.config.js but that did not help either
Removed the UglifyJS references from webpack.prod.config.js, now the error is shown once, instead of 2 times.
Since package.json did not have any entries for Uglify, ran the below command but still the same issue:
npm install uglify-js --save-dev

How can we resolve this issue and deploy the code?

it looks rather like a webpack issue, than angular. try from here: UglifyJs unexpected token error
